# For Loop deletes all rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have never coded in VBA before and am trying to teach myself based off Youtube videos right now which is proving difficult. I am attempting to do a for loop that deletes a row if it does not equal the Part Number, and if the part number is correct, I want the loop to do nothing and move on. I have been typing up random lists of numbers to test my code on, but when I run it, every single row is deleted (even the ones with the correct part number). Ultimately, when I run this on the real data the part number will be a combination of letters and numbers as well as a dash, so I should be storing the Part Number as a string variable correct? Any advice?

```
Sub CodingPrac()
Dim PartNum As String
PartNum = InputBox("Enter the Part Number", "Part Number", "Type value here")
lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = lastrow To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = "PartNum" Then
        Else
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
If Cells(i, 1).Value = "PartNum" Then
```

with:

```
If Cells(i, 1).Value = PartNum Then
```

you need the value of the variable, not a string.

**EDIT#1:**

Your code (as posted) would work if column **A** was like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much @Gary'sStudent!

Comment: What are the quotation marks doing in this case to make the code run improperly?

Comment: @AnaliaQuirk  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: I hope this is a good time to mention that `Cells(i, 1).Value = PartNum` is a case sensitive comparison.

Comment: @Jeeped  Thank you

Comment: Just wanted to mention that since the comparison string is supplied by the user and I've found users to be notoriously unreliable. Every time I build something idiot-proof the world just builds a better idiot,